# C++ Dependencies on MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, dependencies, otool

I am compiling a c++ networking console app on MacOS with a bunch of static libraries.
I can see a C++ runtime, curl, and system dylib as a dependency of the application:

```
$  otool -L test_application
    /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 9.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1300.23.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1311.100.3)
```

The curl comes with static CurlPP, a c++ wrapper for CURL, and the others are implicit. Are these system-level dylibs that I do not need to deploy and is there a way to know this programmatically and not just seeing if it runs on a clean machine?

Comment: You can't modify `/usr/lib` normally on a modern macos version so anything in there is a system library

Comment: I'd go along with that.  Might be worth testing on older versions of macOS though, mainly in case they ship an older version of curl that is missing some feature that you're using.  I use VirtualBox for this kind of thing.